# Compilation error with react-native-reanimated and babel

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, react-native-reanimated

I would like to add `react-native-reanimated` to my project, I followed the [installation guide](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation) and at the time of adding the plugin for Babel I receive an error from it when launching the application :

```
error: index.js: [BABEL] W:\folders\project\index.js: Unknown option: .pre. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.
```

I am using an `Android device`, and therefore I have enabled Hermes and created the method in MainApplication. How can I solve this problem? Do I have to publish an issue on GitHub?

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```

**Dependencies**

```
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-reanimated": "2.3.0-beta.1",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
```

Solution tried:

- Run `react-native start --reset-cache`.
- Delete node_modules and reinstall.
- Changing the library version.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same issue and then realized that it should be in `plugins`, not `presets`. Simply move `'react-native-reanimated/plugin'` into plugins:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
-   'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
+ plugins: [
+   'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
+ ],
}
```

Comment: for me i had written `plugin` instead of `plugins` 

Comment: life saver, thanks @draperunner